# The proof of the homotopy extension and lifting property (HELP)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am reading J. P. May's [Book](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf), the section about homotopy extension and lifting property (HELP) on page 75:

[image]

I know this is true for 
$$(X,A)=(D^n,S^{n-1})\cong (CS^{n-1},S^{n-1}),$$
where $CS^{n-1}$ is the unreduced cone $S^{n-1}\times I/S^{n-1}\times \{1\}$.

But I have no idea about how to prove for general CW pair. I tried to use induction by extending the diagram on the left side with the push out diagram $S^{n-1}\to D^{n}$ and $S^{n-1}\to X^{n}$ where $X^n$ is the $n$-skeleton of $X$. But it did not work.

Could anyone give more details that how this induction works? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See Lemma 2.3 in this [notes](http://math.colorado.edu/~agbe5088/math6280/classnotes/Class18.pdf) by Agnès Beaudry.